# What is the difference between service level authorization and global level authorization?

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

http://google.github.io/google-api-nodejs-client/10.0.0/index.html

The link above gives examples of giving service level and global level auth, but I can't figure out what those are just from googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mostly used in the context of a microservice architecture.

In global-level authorization, a user (can be a person or a service, such as a 3rd party service) is authorized once (preferably by an authorization server running as a microservice) and all the microservices have to respect that the user is authorized/unauthorized to access their resource. They can't make a decision on their own.

In service-level authorization, the entitlements of the user are given to the microservice. The services get to know of what the user's permissions are and thus they do the authorization based on that information, thus leading to a fine-grained control on how the resource is accessed.